# О голосовании на сайте

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Для улучшения работы сайта и  объективной оценки значимости ответов я предлагаю следующее:

**1. Обозначать голоса "за и против" поименно, "тайное голосование" лишено объективности**

Посредственные ответы могут набирать большое количество голосов, если участник имеет "группу поддержки". Допустим, мне он нравится и поэтому я голосую за него, а не за ответ. Наверное, при анонимном голосовании возможны и другие варианты "приписок".

Также важно знать, кто именно поддержал ответ: известный участник, которому я доверяю, или новичок, которого никто еще не знает.

**2. Знак "минус" может быть обжалован в особой комиссии**

Пусть в спорных случаях общество решает, насколько полезен ответ. К примеру, рассмотрим мой вариант, который получил знак "минус", что в нем "не полезного"? [Нужна ли запятая перед «несмотря на»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432367/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0)

1. дан четкий ответ на поставленный вопрос;
2. приведено общее правило Розенталя на эту тему, а также исключение с замечанием о тесной смысловой связи;
3. приведены и прокомментированы примеры из Нацкорпуса.

Даже если кто-то иначе понимает тесную смысловую связь, это не повод минусовать ответ, да еще безо всяких пояснений. Вот мне и хочется узнать, кто поставил минус и почему.

Comment: @ Sibylla, полностью поддерживаю вас, т. к. минусы на нашем сайте ставят только те, кто не способен объяснить свою точку зрения. Зато свои ответы считают истиной в последней инстанции.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за поддержку.  Если обратиться к истории форума,  то можно сделать вывод: минусы ставят только ОТДЕЛЬНЫЕ участники (один-два человека) и ставят не всем, а вполне ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫМ лицам (при этом все остальные ответы они, видимо,  считают идеальными). Даже из этого можно сделать вывод, какова истинная направленность этих минусов. К объективной оценке  ответа они вряд ли имеют отношение.

Comment: @ Sibylla, здесь много участников, парой наши мнения не сходятся. Даже если кто-то ошибся, это не повод лепить минусы. Если лепить минусу тем участником, кто ставят минусы, то больше половины их ответов надо удалять, в них нет никакой конкретики, пользы. В большинстве случаев не хочется связываться.

Comment: Связываться не хочется, но хотелось бы добиться хотя бы какой-нибудь защиты.  Может быть, не имеет смысла рассматривать единичные случаи. Но если один и тот же человек изо дня в день ставит минусы практически на все мои вопросы и ответы, то разве это не повод обратиться к руководству сайта.

Comment: Не только на ваши,на ответы многих участников тоже, в том числе и мои. Толку нету.

Comment: В последние дни "война минусов" перешла уже все границы, по-моему. Увы, увы, увы! По-моему, админ должен вмешаться - и я надеюсь, что он вмешается. Я тоже обращался. Но "минус за минус" - не метод борьбы.

Comment: Совершенно с Вами согласна.  Тут на пару дней было временное затишье, все вроде вздохнули свободно. Но нет, очередная атака на отвечающих со стороны одного лица, когда  минус ставится за ссылку на Розенталя или за редактирование явно неудачного перевода, то есть за обычную работу на форуме, когда  одни люди надеются получить ответы, а другие стараются ответить.  Объяснения, которые при этом даются, не стоят ничего (пишется первое, что придет в голову).

Comment: И как с этим бороться?  Предложений нет, остается единственное оружие - минусовка в ответ. На такие страницы сайта стыдно смотреть. Предлагаю объявить МОРАТОРИЙ  на все минусы хотя бы временно.

Comment: @Aer Можете Вы как модератор стать посредником в объявлении  МОРАТОРИЯ на минусы на какое-то время?  От отсутсвия минусов вреда немного, а вот от их неуемного применения вред большой: вводит читателей в заблуждение и портит нервы авторам ответов.

Comment: @М_Г и Sibylla, пожалуйста, зайдите в чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61487/.

Answer (score 3):

В рамках поставленного вопроса (о минусах). По правилам минус означает отсутствие полезности. Если участник высказывает свое субъективное мнение - не факт, что оно бесполезно для читателей, тем более если участник опытный и авторитетный (это определяется количеством набранных балов). По моему, нужно быть осторожнее с минусами и использовать их строго в соответствии с критерием полезности. И конечно нетерпимо, когда минус ставится в отместку (такие случаи заметны в последнее время). Но я не вижу алтернативы принципу стихийной самоорганизации сообщества, а это значит, что я против предложенных @Sibylla изменений. Это ИМХО, как теперь пишут, и с большим уважением к более опытным участникам.

Comment: 1) Я считаю, что минус нужно ставить только за явно ОШИБОЧНУЮ информацию,   противоречащую  основным правилам письма (что ни в ком не вызывает сомнений). Можно также предварительно предложить автору исправить ошибку. Формулировку о полезности или бесполезности ответа надо бы изменить, это  чисто субъективная оценка. 2) Я считаю неправильным ставить минус  за ответы на дискуссионные вопросы, а таких здесь большинство. Это просто проявление неуважения к чужому мнению.

Comment: 3) Нет никаких сомнений, что знак минус в последнее время используется для сведения счетов с неугодными людьми.  Для нормальной дискуссии достаточно оставить комментарий, если ответ вам не нравится. 4) Я никогда не ставила минусов, но сейчас  ставлю их только одному участнику, который регулярно "минусует"  мои ответы, но у  меня нет других способов защититься от него. 5) Мне хотелось бы знать, кто и как голосует поименно. Решение этого вопроса чисто техническое, но оно существенно повысило бы объективность оценок на форуме.

Comment: @М_Г, а как быть, когда минусуют, исходя из субъективных мнений?

Comment: @Серж, Я уже писал: любое мнение субъективно, этом сайте нет абсолютный авторитетов. Все-таки должна быть демократия, самоорганизация, а это значит каждый должен чувствовать личную ответственность и играть по правилам. А о правилах мы должны договориться. Я думаю, принцип должен быть такой: ставь минус только если ты абсолютно уверен в своей правоте и добавь комментарий с объяснением. Я не думаю, что кто-то сознательно хочет навредить. Просто некоторые из участников - анархисты в душе. Но если большинство будет призывать их к порядку, они прислушаются.

Comment: @ М_Г, я согласен с вами. Но те, кто ставят минус ( в основном это пару человек) ставят минусы, исходя из субъективного мнения. "Я ставлю, потому что я не согласен", - это их ответ.  Никаких доказательств привести не могут.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, за всей этой темой стоит личная обида. Но коли вы привели этот пример вопроса-ответа, давайте о нем и поговорим. Попробую помочь вам разобраться.

> Даже если кто-то иначе понимает тесную смысловую связь, это не повод
>   минусовать ответ

Это **ваше** мнение. Кто-то, может, считает, что как раз повод. Но обычно ответы (подобные вашему) вызывают негативную оценку как раз потому, что вы **свое понимание** выдаете за единственно возможное и не готовы объяснить свой выбор.

Если говорить по существу, ваши ответы вообще очень часто далеки от конкретики. В ответе по ссылке я вообще не вижу ответа. Я вообще не продрался через частокол лирических отступлений.

Далее. Не вижу там минусов (или из плюсами замазали?), но вижу в комментариях к вопросу чью-то попытку разобраться. Не знаю, насколько удачна сама эта попытка, но первые два комментария вполне разумны.

Вашу мысль я бы оформил примерно так.
.----
Ответ (у вас - "запятая ошибочна").

Краткое объяснение (у вас это будет цитата из Розенталя и ваш вывод).

> Цитата из Розенталя - с указанием источника.

В этом предложении есть тесная смысловая связь, поэтому запятая ошибочна.
.----

Больше вы ничего по существу не сказали. Но при этом сразу видны слабые места такой позиции.

*1. У Розенталя нет императивности.

2. Мнение о наличии тесной связи субъективно.*

Вот это я бы вам с большим удовольствием написал в комментариях. Но не думаю, что это воздействует. Субъективность у вас зашкаливает - за это, думаю, и минусы вам ставят.

И еще по вашим ответам. Вы совершенно не умеете оформлять ссылки и цитаты. Пишете собственный текст под видом цитаты. Или наоборот, даете цитату без грамотного указания на источник. Но вы, правда, тут не одна такая. Есть еще авторы, которые просто не понимают, что любое правило применимо при определенных условиях. И цитата с ссылкой на источник нужна не для удовольствия, а для проверки адекватности понимания.

Я не отпираюсь, минусовал. Но всегда сначала старался разобраться. Не получив ответа по существу выражал свое мнение через систему голосования. 
Но я и сам минусы получаю изрядное количество. Причем без комментариев.

> Для улучшения работы сайта и объективной оценки значимости ответов

А объективная оценка - это ваша?! Не будет её никогда. Объективность голосования возможна только через некоторую статистическую субъективность или экспертную оценку. Но это не наш случай.

Понимаете, в чем дело. Минусы-то ставят не случайные люди. Это привилегия дается за некоторые заслуги. И те, кто их ставят, тоже мнят себя экспертами. И считают свою оценку объективной.

***Но у меня вопрос к модераторам. А что, "работу сайта" уже пора улучшать? И именно в этом направлении?*** Так вы только скажите.

> Знак "минус" может быть обжалован в особой комиссии

Ну а это вообще смешно. )))
Еще партсобрание предложите провести. Это сколько же надо иметь бездельников, которые денно и нощно будут разбирать обоснованность каждого минуса? Sibylla, **минус - это элемент системы учета мнений**. Мнений, Карл. А не их обоснованности.

Я ответил, зная, что Sibylla на меня почему-то зуб точит. Сим показываю, что я открыт для диалога. Хотя по большому счету диалог тут не нужен. Вопрос не стоит времени, на него потраченного, а личные отношения не должны переноситься на вопросы и ответы.

Answer (score -2):

Мы начали проверку приведенной вами в комментариях и вопросах информации по поводу "войны минусов". Вскоре будут приняты необходимые меры.

Comment: Спасибо, проверяйте. И обязательно учтите, что я никогда  не ставила минусы за ответы, пока не стала получать их ежедневно ( и не по одному)  от одного и того же лица. В данный момент я ставлю минус только после того, как получаю его сама, другого выхода у меня нет. Таково моё участие в этой войне "минусов".

Comment: @Sibylla боюсь, что любое участие в "войне минусов" нарушает правила. Мы постараемся учесть все обстоятельства в расследовании.

Comment: Я обращалась к вам за помощью, не поставив еще ни одного минуса, но мне никто не помог.  Я много времени трачу на ответы, тщательно их обдумываю, сверяю с источниками, привожу текстовые примеры.  Если  высказываю собственное мнение, то обязательно указываю на это. На сайте обычно обсуждаются  сложные вопросы, не все они имеют однозначный ответ. Так почему надо, высказав свое мнение, перечеркнуть минусом мнение остальных. Это - нормально?  Запретите "участникам войны" (вы троих, кажется. насчитали) ставить минусы на пару месяцев. Увидите, как всё сразу станет тихо и благопристойно.

Comment: И Что теперь?  Пока я вижу что удалили часть моих минусов (числом около двух с половиной десятков). Это и есть необходимые меры? Ну а что мешает мне поставить их вновь?! Я же не ставлю их немотивировано?! И потом, почему тогда поставленные мне не убрали?! Ерундой вы занялись. Если нельзя ставить - ну так и скажите. А такие меры ни к чему хорошему не приведут.  Минус мой.

Comment: @Мимоходов расследование все еще продолжается; на данный момент не все подозрительные голоса были аннулированы. Конечно, ставить минусы можно и нужно — но соблюдая правила сайта и руководствуясь не эмоциями. Если, как и просит система, обосновывать свой минус, будет возникать меньше вопросов.

Comment: Я не ставил немотивированных минусов. И в чем состоигт расследование простите? В рнахожденири авторов поставивших минусы Sibylla и отмене их?! Что у нас за неприкасаемые завелись?! Мне честно говоря пофигу на все эти минусы, неприятно, что придумываются какие-то "правила" в угоду автору, не слишком  страдающему объективностью самооценки.

Comment: Короче, если не будет ясно сказано, что минусы ставить нельзя, восстанавливаю всё незаслуженно убранные минусы.

Comment: @Мимоходов ведется проверка сообщений участников о "войне минусов". Пожалуйста, дождитесь ее окончания.

Comment: Я не знаю, чего вы там там проверяете, но я уже вижу решение с которым я категорически не согласен. И не собираюсь чего-то еще ждать на основании каких-то анонимных сообщений.

Comment: @Мимоходов еще раз прошу вас дождаться результатов расследования.

Comment: Уважаемый  Aer, оставлвляю за собой право не признавать ваших решений, принятых по анонимкам. Ваше "расследование" изначально противоречит правилам ресурса и морально-правовым нормам. Что это за заочное осуждение?! Меня даже не спросили, за что я ставил минусы. Надо думать, я не один такой.

Comment: @Мимоходов обращаю ваше внимание на то, что расследование ведется командой модераторов и администрацией сайта. Вы можете отвечать на письма, приходящие вам от команды модераторов. Я не уполномочен обсуждать санкции, примененные к кому-либо, в комментариях.

Comment: Как я могу отвечать на письма, если там стоит "no-reply"? А сообщения у  Сибиллы в массе низкокачественные.

Comment: @Мимоходов я говорил про возможность ответа через сайт, нажмите на пришедшее уведомление.